# Calculation of average current across load in silicon controlled half wave rectifier

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier

I know that when anode to cathode current of thyristor drops below holding current then thyristor turns off. I actually stuck in solving numerical problem where i need to calculate average current in load when holding current is 200mA (but no Zero).
[image: Numerical Question]

Comment: You should first draw and post a schematic diagram according to your understanding of the problem. Then add operating waveforms like the input sinusoidal voltage feeding your circuit, then the current and voltage across the resistive load, highlighting where the SCR starts conducting and when it stops.

Comment: I found that at angle of 30° thyristor starts conduction. If holding current would have been zero, thyristor would conduct from 30° to 180°. But i am not sure how to use current waveform to calculate conduction range (30° to some angle less than 180° according to my understanding). Maximum input current would be 2A at 90°. It means that thyristor will turns off between 90° to 180° when holding current drops below 200mA. I am stuck and don't have any ideas other than this. If there is some resources that i could follow, will be very helpful.

Comment: Just write now (is the same thing for finding starting conduction angle ...) that 200m = 2 * sin(alpha) where alpha is the unknown (2 solutions, just choose the right).

Comment: The waveforms are those kindly simulated by *Antonio51*. You must modify them to account for the blocking of the SCR when the current falls below 200 mA (for the last bullet in your questions list) and that will give you the conduction angle. Once you have the current waveform, with or without the holding current, then you need to integrate it between 0 and the time during which the current is non-zero - the conducting time - and divide the result by the line period. This will give you the average current flowing in the load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration of what pointed out by @Verbal Kint

You have all that is needed to complete your calculation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It means that angle between 174.26° to 180 thyristor doesn't conduct and conducts the angle between 30° to 174.26°?

Comment: Right. Well seen. My simulation does not account that the SCR (not the same as the question, of course) switches off at 200 mA. Note also that angle could be different because as the SCR voltage drop  is ~ 1.6 V,  current at max is not 2 A but very near (1.984 A).